# Google Apps Script sidebar html not handling if statement?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps Script sidebar where a user submits a form.

```
  <script>
    function form_data(){
        if(!$("#file").get(0).files.length||$("#range").val()=="") return;
        $("#progress").text("uploading");
        console.log($("#file").get(0).files[0])
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(done).withFailureHandler(fail).upload($("form")[0]);
      };
      function getSelected(){
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(annotation){$("#range").val(annotation)}).getSelected();
      }
      function done(e){
        $("#progress").text("");
        $("#file").val("");
        $("#range").val("")
      };
      function fail(e){
        let errorMessage = e;
        $("#progress").text(`Failed with error: ${errorMessage}`);
      }
  </script>
```

This works fine, and when there's a failure, the fail(e) is working.
But I want to add some custom error messages, which isn't working.

In the fail(e) function, I changed it to this:

```
      function fail(e){
        var errorMessage = e;
        if(errorMessage.indexOf("a server error occurred")>-1) {
           errorMessage = "Custom error message. try again later";
        }
        $("#progress").text(`Failed with error: ${errorMessage}`);
      }
```

...and it stops working.

Why doesn't that if statement work? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, unfortunately, I cannot know your function of `upload` at Google Apps Script side, as a simple modification, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
function fail(e){
  var errorMessage = e;
  if(errorMessage.indexOf("a server error occurred")>-1) {
     errorMessage = "Custom error message. try again later";
  }
  $("#progress").text(`Failed with error: ${errorMessage}`);
}
```

#### To:

```
function fail(e){
  var errorMessage = e.message; // Modified
  if(errorMessage.indexOf("a server error occurred")>-1) {
     errorMessage = "Custom error message. try again later";
  }
  $("#progress").text(`Failed with error: ${errorMessage}`);
}
```

- By this modification, `var errorMessage = e.message;` is the error message from Google Apps Script side.

#### Note:

- If your function of `upload` at Google Apps Script side has try-catch and the error message is returned as `return value`, `withSuccessHandler(done)` is run. Please be careful about this. In order to execute `withFailureHandler(fail)`, it is required to occur an error, for example, by using `throw new Error("###")`.

#### Reference:

- [withFailureHandler(function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withfailurehandlerfunction)